# Firefox SDK - Detecting back button in extension

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'd like to do the equivalent of chrome.tabs.onUpdated in Firefox. tabs.on('ready', function(tab){}) does not work because it does not detect the back button. How do I fire an action on every page load such that it also detects the back button using the [Firefox SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.13/modules/sdk/tabs.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently impossible, but will be possible in a future version of Firefox:
https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/commit/e4ce238090a6e243c542c2b421f5906ef465acd0

Comment: They have now implemented the `pageshow` event into the `tabs` module, so it is now possible (you may want to update your answer)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use `require('window-utils').WindowTracker` to all windows, filter for browser windows with the `require('sdk/window/utils').isBrowser(window)` method, then listen to click events on the back button.

Comment: Thanks. How would I listen for click events on the back button? Also would that work if they go back with another method such as hitting the backspace key?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a late answer, but for anyone reading this now (from 2016), **it is now possible to do using the SDK**!

Using the High-Level API `tabs`, you need to listen for the [`pageshow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#pageshow) event. (More about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pageshow))

An example:

```
tabs.on('pageshow', function(tab) {
    // Your code here
})
```

It is very similar to the `load` and `ready` events, the main difference being that is is also fired when a page is loaded from [`BFCache`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_BFCache) (which it is when the back button is pressed).

Answer (score -1):

I think the following snippet gives the functionality of chrome.tabs.onUpdated

```js
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.on('ready', function(tab){
  console.log(tab.url);
});
```

Comment: My understanding was that your question had two parts. I answered the first.

Comment: Frefox's tabs.on('ready', function(){}) is not equivalent to chrome.tabs.onUpdated. It behaves very differently.